# Does different partial specialization in different compiler unit defined behavior in C++?

Tags: c++

For example, suppose I have a template class foo in foo.h like below:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    constexpr static auto value = false;
};
```

in first.cpp file, I use the foo like below:

```
#include "foo.h"
auto dummy1() {
    return foo<int>::value;
}
```

in second.cpp file, I write partial specialization for foo and use foo like below:

```
#include "foo.h"
template <std::integral T>
struct foo<T> {
    constexpr static auto value = true;
};

auto dummy2() {
    return foo<int>::value;
}
```

It's such program a well defined behavior in c++? What if dummy2 use unsigned int like below:

```
auto dummy2() {
    return foo<unsigned int>::value;
}
```

Comment: First things first, that is an "explicit specialization" and not a "partial specialization"

Comment: See dupe [Explicit specialization of member function template in source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530364/explicit-specialization-of-member-function-template-in-source-file)

Comment: sorry, I have updated problem now. @JasonLiam

Comment: See [Is partial specialization in a cpp file not "well-formed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755029/is-partial-specialization-in-a-cpp-file-not-well-formed/31755465#31755465)

Answer (score 1):

That's *explicit speciliaztion*, not *partial specialization*, and yes it makes the program IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required) which effectively means the same as undefined behavior for all inputs.

See [[temp.expl.spec]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.expl.spec#7.sentence-1) which requires the explicit specialization to be declared before first use that would cause implicit instantiation of the specialization in every translation unit where such use is present.

---

After the update of the question:

Now it is indeed a partial specialization, but basically the same holds. See [[temp.class.spec.general]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.class.spec.general#1.sentence-5) for the equivalent sentence regarding partial specializations.

So you need to at least add a declaration of the partial specialization to the header:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    constexpr static auto value = false;
};

template <std::integral T>
struct foo<T>;
```

Although then it won't be enough to resolve `foo<int>::value`, so you are back to needing to put the whole definition of the partial specialization into the header.

Comment: sorry, I have updated the problem.